# 2002PT Cruiser intermittent start/cranking issues

Tags: starting, ignition, intermittent-problems

Have issues for two years. Replaced battery 3x -found sensor draining and repeated start attempts. Replaced alternator, starter 2x last 2/16/2021. Failed to crank 2/17. All interior lights and blinkers strong. Finally moved gear shifters neutral. Kicked right over! I expect a recurrence. Five subsequent starts good.2002 pt CRUISER

Answer (score 1):

You most likely have a faulty neutral safety switch. This switch is activated when the transmission is in the park and neutral position. It's a way to prevent it from starting in gear. Other things that could affect the neutral safety switch to not function are loose or worn shifter linkage or loose or worn linkage at the transmission.